# Facebook Graph API split test for audience

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, https, facebook-marketing-api

I am attempting to create a Facebook split test comparing how two different target audiences respond to one ad.

I am having some trouble finding the correct endpoint for this feature however, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-study/) is the document I am currently reading and suspect is in the right direction, however where do I specify that I am testing the audience instead of say the creatives or delivery optimization?

Is it an entirely different endpoint? Am I just missing the parameter somewhere? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does Facebook even (still) allow for that? I hope not … because that sounds like a perfect tool, if someone wanted to stir sh*t up politically. Getting direct feedback on how on edge you could get “magas” vs “libtards” with certain ads? Sounds like a dream wetter than Moscow hotel mattresses.

Comment: I'm also looking for more info on split testing. To me it seems that you have to first create different Ad Sets, where the difference is optimally in a single attribute (and the same attribute). As that page doesn't mention budget, I think the budget configured for those Ad Sets will be used, and by default no copies will be made. Does anyone have actual experience with this?